# RESTeasy: Pass through all query params

Tags: java, resteasy

We have a proxy API set up where we accept any path after our proxy (i.e. `/proxy/some/path`) and then everything after the proxy path should be forwarded on to another API using RESTeasy (so it would call `/some/path` in my example).

This is necessary for us for several reasons including avoiding CORS issues and it works most of the time for what we need.  However, some routes require query parameters some or all of the time, and because we are handling all routes the same, this causes a RESTeasy error today since the URL gets URL encoded to something like `/some/path%3ffilter=value`.

Our endpoint today looks like:

```
@Path("proxy/{someUri : .*}")
@GET
public Response proxyGet(
        @PathParam("someUri") String someUri,
        @HeaderParam(COOKIE) String cookieHeader,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request
) {
    return prepareProxyResponse(someUri, cookieHeader, request, null);
}
```

Our RESTeasy interface looks like:

```
@GET
@Path("/{requestPath}")
Response proxyGet(
        @PathParam("requestPath") String requestPath,
        @HeaderParam(COOKIE) String sessionCookie,
        @HeaderParam(CONTENT_TYPE) String contentType
);
```

The code that calls this looks like:

```
return client.proxyGet(fullPath, cookieHeader, contentTypeHeader);
```

Prior to understanding this issue, we just took the request URI and added the query string to it so the requestPath above looked like `some/path?filter=value` which gets mangled.  Removing the query string avoids that, however, it also means we cannot pass any query params through.

Is there a way to accept any query params and submit them to the other API using RESTeasy?  I know we can break these out where needed to manually specify query params with @QueryParam but since there are many (and more getting added regularly) this will be a lot of effort.  I think accomplishing what we are trying to do is not possible based on my research in other questions and the docs, but wanted to double-check before we embarked on a long process to convert. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried injecting the `UriInfo`? That should provide you with all the information you need.

Comment: I saw an example with UriInfo to get query params programmatically but not how that could be used to automatically forward all submitted query params to the other API.  Do you have an example of how to accomplish what I need using UriInfo?

Comment: How do you send the new request? Are you using a client which creates a new request and response?

Comment: Yes, I included the code we use in my question, but we use RESTeasy to create a client.  The only thing I didn't include was how we call this client so I just edited it to include that code as well.

Comment: I guess one question is why not use a `ContainerRequestFilter` instead of trying to re-do a call?